# SpringBoot War deployed not available without errors

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat7

I've created a war file from a SpringBoot appl. ( Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine). The root / redirects to a welcome page

This is the main class:

```
@Profile("war")
@Import({SecurityConfig.class ,PersistenceConfig.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class BookCloudApplicationWar extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(BookCloudApplicationWar.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(BookCloudApplicationWar.class, args);
    }   
}
```

This is my application.properties

```
server.contextPath=/book
server.port=8080
```

This is the tomcat console, no errors:

```
Mar 16, 2017 7:50:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/bookcloud-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

But I got a 404 accessing

http://149.142.221.107:8080/bookcloud-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/

or

http://149.142.221.107:8080/bookcloud-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/book

or

http://149.142.221.107:8080/book

or

http://149.142.221.107:8080/book/book

and no errors in the console

Here the MANIFEST.MF inside the war

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: bookcloud
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: nunito
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.tdk
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.5.2.RELEASE
Implementation-Vendor: Pivotal Software, Inc.
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
Start-Class: com.tdk.BookCloudApplicationWar
Spring-Boot-Classes: WEB-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: WEB-INF/lib/
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_77
Implementation-URL: http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/bookcloud/
```

and in the tomcat managet application interface it seems that this application is running bookcloud-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: What kind of application is this? Do you have an webpage or rest api which you can access to check if application is up and running?

Comment: `server.contextPath` in application.properties will only work with embedded tomcat. So if using embedded tomcat `http://server:port/book`, if app is deployed in an standalone tomcat installation app welcome page will be at `http://sever:port/war-name/`

Comment: that was my first option :-(

Comment: Try configuring the tomcat manager interface, there you can see what applications are deployed, what are running. http://blog.techstacks.com/2009/05/tomcat-management-setting-up-tomcat.html